# Moving the ActionBarTabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I've set up a ViewPager in my App with tabs, but I need to position the tabs underneath a button so the layout would be

```
               TitleBar
Button to search activities on a day
Tabs of each day there are activities
```

Is that kind of layout possible to do using Tabs or will I need a different approach to solve this?

The way the activity is running is theres a main activity, and the layout is just the button and a FrameLayout, and the the list (where the ViewPager is) is set up in a fragment and the fragment is loaded into the FrameLayout. I don't know if this is the best method for this so if not please add your recommendations of a better method I could use.

EDIT: If I could get it so all the tabs were at the bottom of the screen this would also be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that kind of layout possible to do using Tabs

Not with action bar tabs. Not only can you not control where the tabs go, you cannot even control if there will be tabs versus a drop-down list.

> will I need a different approach to solve this?

You are welcome to use some other tab solution (`ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, `FragmentTabHost`, etc.) where you have more control.

Note that your proposed design does not adhere to Android design aesthetics. Most apps would not have "Button to search activities on a day", but instead a search action bar item, or perhaps a `SearchView` in the action bar.

> If I could get it so all the tabs were at the bottom of the screen this would also be fine.

This is completely against the Android design guidelines. [Don't use bottom tab bars on Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html).

Comment: I realize the Button is unusual, however, my boss wants to have a dedicated search button, however, I will try and talk her around to having a menu item. Thanks for the tip about Tabbed indicator and FragmentTabHost, I've not used them yet so I'll look into it now.